# R string removes punctuation on split

Tags: regex, r

Say I have a string for example the following.

```
x <- 'The world is at end. What do you think?   I am going crazy!    These people are too calm.'
```

I need to split only on the punctuation `!?.` and following whitespace and keep the punctuation with it.

This removes the punctuation and leaves leading spaces in the split parts though

```
vec <- strsplit(x, '[!?.][:space:]*')
```

How can I split sentences leaving the punctuation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can switch on [`PCRE`](http://www.pcre.org/) by using `perl=TRUE` and use a lookbehind assertion.

```
strsplit(x, '(?<![^!?.])\\s+', perl=TRUE)
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<!          look behind to see if there is not:
 [^!?.]       any character except: '!', '?', '.'
)             end of look-behind
\s+           whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/dEHCb7)

Comment: is the reason that the `'.'` does not need to be escaped because it is in a `[ ]` group or for some other reason?

Comment: For PCRE, and other so-called Perl-compatible flavors, escape `.^$*+?()[{\|` outside character class and `^`, `-`, `]`, \ inside character class.

Comment: So if i set perl = true i can use different assertions?

Answer (score 6):

The `sentSplit` function in the [qdap package](https://github.com/trinker/qdap) was create just for this task:

```
library(qdap)
sentSplit(data.frame(text = x), "text")

##   tot                       text
## 1 1.1       The world is at end.
## 2 2.2         What do you think?
## 3 3.3          I am going crazy!
## 4 4.4 These people are too calm.
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525408/r-regular-expressions-unexpected-behavior-of-digit). Character classes like `[:space:]` are defined within bracket expressions, so you need to enclose it in a set of brackets. Try:

```
vec <- strsplit(x, '[!?.][[:space:]]*')
vec
# [[1]]
# [1] "The world is at end"       "What do you think"        
# [3] "I am going crazy"          "These people are too calm"
```

This gets rid of the leading spaces. To keep punctuation, use a positive lookbehind assertion with `perl = TRUE`:

```
vec <- strsplit(x, '(?<=[!?.])[[:space:]]*', perl = TRUE)
vec
# [[1]]
# [1] "The world is at end."       "What do you think?"        
# [3] "I am going crazy!"          "These people are too calm."
```

Comment: He wanted the punctuation after the split also.

Comment: Ah, got it. I'll edit - it'll look a lot like your answer, just with `[[:space:]]` instead of `\\s`. The overlap of answers isn't 100%, so I'm okay with it if you're okay with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the spaces following punctuation marks with a string, e.g `zzzzz` and then split on that string.

```
x <- gsub("([!?.])[[:space:]]*","\\1zzzzz","The world is at end. What do you think?   I am going crazy!    These people are too calm.")
strsplit(x, "zzzzz")
```

Where `\1` in the replacement string refers to the parenthesized sub-expression of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As of [qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) you can use the `sent_detect` function as follows:

```
library(qdap)
sent_detect(x)

## [1] "The world is at end."       "What do you think?"        
## [3] "I am going crazy!"          "These people are too calm."
```

Comment: Also, as of 2.2.1, sent_detect_nlp