# regular expression to match digit in R

Tags: r

```
> x<-c("01.mp3","invite.mp3")
> x[grep(x,pattern="[:digit:]")]
[1] "invite.mp3"
```

In the regular expression,Why i can not get "01.mp3"?

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525408/r-regular-expressions-unexpected-behavior-of-digit) for a discussion and links to explanations of why it doesn't work.  What will work is `x[grep(x,pattern="[[:digit:]]")]` or `x[grep(x,pattern="[0-9]")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get "01.mp3" because it consists of two digits and ".mp3", then you could do something like:

```
x<-c("01.mp3","invite.mp3")
x[grep(x,pattern="[0-9]{2}.mp3")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what's happening here (and someone will presumably correct me), is that you are not actually matching what you think you are. You need to put the bracket list `[:digit:]` inside brackets to match the list, otherwise you are matching the literal characters in `:digit:`. You can see this by adding a third element to `x`:

```
x<-c("01.mp3","invite.mp3", ":")
x[grep(pattern="[:digit:]", x = x)]
#[1] "invite.mp3" ":"
```

So `[:digit]` will match `:` as well. If instead, you use `[[`:

```
x[grep(x,pattern="[[:digit:]]")]
#[1] "01.mp3"     "invite.mp3"
```

you are then matching the class digit.